# Using GameCube discs on wii (controller)

Tags: controllers, nintendo-wii, nintendo-gamecube

I know I can use a GameCube disc on a wii but to play them do I need to use a GameCube controller or I can use a Wii

Answer (score 3):

According to [Nintendo Support](https://www.nintendo.co.uk/Support/Parents/Hardware/Wii/Can-I-play-Nintendo-GameCube-games-on-Wii-/Can-I-play-Nintendo-GameCube-games-on-Wii--659664.html), you cannot play GameCube games with a Wii Remote.

> Please note that the Wii Remote cannot be used to play GameCube games, and that standard GameCube controllers or the wireless WaveBird variant are required.

This also means that your Wii must have GameCube controller ports in order to play GameCube games:

[image: Wii with open GameCube ports cover]

Despite that, [Nintendo Support](https://www.nintendo.co.uk/Support/Wii/Troubleshooting/Nintendo-GameCube-software-and-accessories/Identifying-if-a-Wii-console-is-compatible-with-Nintendo-GameCube-software-and-accessories-/Nintendo-GameCube-software-and-accessories-242193.html) recommends checking the Wii's Model No. to determine if it's compatible with GameCube games:

> - If the Model No. starts with RVL, the Wii system IS compatible with Nintendo GameCube software and accessories.
> - If the Model No. starts with RVK, the Wii system IS NOT compatible with Nintendo GameCube software and accessories.

Answer (score 1):

If you hack the wii and use nintendont to load your gamecube games, you can play the games with a wiimote and nunchuck or the wii classic controller plugged into the wiimote as well as other usb hid compatible controllers.

Without using home brew you can only play with a gamecube controller.

Comment: I see I got a down vote. Any suggestions to improve the answer?